# Find duplicate PDFs

Tags: pdf, similarity

I'm looking for a utility that will help me find duplicate PDFs.  The problem:  I have a 1000s of PDF files.  Some are duplicates.  They are not easy to detect due differing files names and small differences in file size.  Is there a utility/algorithm/library that can help me find the duplicates or show me files that are very similar (or degree of difference)?

Comment: Just found a utility that may work: http://anti-twin.com/

Answer (score 3):

Create an MD5 hash for each file and store it in a database. Identical files will then sort next to each other, or you can quickly search for a pre-existing key.

Answer (score 2):

If the files were created by the different tools, they could look the same but generate very different results because they are structured totally differently. I made some suggestions in a blog article at https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/09/comparing-2-pdf-files/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not yet solved in any way. What I do, is I use fdupes http://premium.caribe.net/~adrian2/fdupes.html to find exact duplicates.

But most of all, I use a workflow which minimizes duplicates. Every document that enters my system gets indexed with this perl-script I wrote: http://seegras.discordia.ch/Programs/fileindex which puts some name and an md5-sum of it into ~/.fileindex.md5 Now I can change metadata of the local PDF-files or whatever (and run fileindex again), and whenever I accidently download the same file again, I will stil lhave the md5-sum of the original file, and thus can detect whether it's a duplicate.

There's also exif-meta and exif-rename on http://seegras.discordia.ch/Programs/ which help with setting PDF metadata and with renaming PDF-files according to metadata; and if you're tagging all the files correctly, you will end up with duplicate filenames, indicating that they might be the same document within a different file.

Answer (score 1):

[DiffPDF](http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html) looks like something that might help you.

Comment: DiffPDF compares 2 files side by side.  Unfortunately, I have 1000s of files to compare so an automated solution would be best.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that there is a UNIX utility called pdf2txt (see the package `poppler-utils`). You can try to extract the text from the files and make a textual diff.